# Помогите написать регулярное для split

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно регулярное выражение для split в js, для разбития строки по символам [ и ],
например "example [example1]" --> example, example1

Comment: тут лучше подойдёт не split, а соответствие паттерну: «что-угодно (запоминаем), пробел, [, что-угодно-кроме-] (запоминаем), ]»

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали сделать? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: да я как-бы еще не совсем понимаю сам принцип создания регулярных выражений

Comment: я пробовал так, но это не работает /\[[\w]\]/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут лучше подойдёт не split, а соответствие паттерну: «что-угодно *(запоминаем)*, пробел, [, что-угодно-кроме-] *(запоминаем)*, ]»

Мой любимый справочник по регулярным выражениям: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) (на англ.), а это [на русском](http://regexpstudio.com/ru/TRegExpr/Help/regexp_syntax.html) – вроде, есть всё основное.

Написал пример, специально чуть другой. Тут ловится содержание в угловых скобках в начале, и всё, что потом:

```
"<example> example1" --> example, example1
```

вот таким регулярным выражением:

```
\<([^\>]*)\>\ ?(.*)
```

Что тут есть.

- `(что-то)` – в круглые скобки заключаем то, что нужно «вытащить» отдельно – это появится как элемент массива результата;
- `[АБВ]` – в квадратных скобках символы, которые нужны. Если перед ними поставить птичку, то наоборот: всё, кроме этих. `[^АБВ]` – только не А, Б или В;
- `*` или `+` после чего-то означает их кол-во. `*` – ни одного или больше, `+` – один или больше. `[АБВ]+` хочет хотя бы одну из А, Б или В. Больше, чем одна тоже хорошо.
- `\<` – обратным слэшем `\` предваряются всякие спецсимволы, чтобы не путать их значение с их «служебными» функциями. `\<` это просто символ `<`, но он может быть «специальным», поэтому его экранируем;
- `?` знак вопроса допускает неопределённость – символ прямо перед ним может быть, а может и не быть – всем всё равно. `мышь?` допускает и грамотную «мышь» и безграмотную «мыш».

Попробуйте переделать этот паттерн для вашей исходной задачи.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("in-txt");
var output = document.getElementById("out");

function checkit(e) {
  var matches = input.value.match(/\<([^\>]*)\>\ ?(.*)/);
  if( matches) {
    out.innerHTML = "Match: \"" + matches[1] + "\", \"" + matches[2] + "\"";
  } else {
    out.innerHTML = "No match";
  }
}
input.addEventListener("input", checkit);
```

```html
<link href="https://yastatic.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="in-txt">Напечатайте текст:</label>
<input type="text" id="in-txt" placeholder="<example> example1">
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Экранировать `<`, `>` необязательно.